# Manually trigger swipe up gesture event in Safari on IOS 15+

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, mobile-safari

The fullscreen view in Safari on IOS 15 isn't being triggered when JavaScript is used to deploy a scroll down effect. This fullscreen view only seems to show when the screen is physically swiped up a little.

| DEFAULT IOS BEHAVIOR ON SWIPE DOWN | JAVASCRIPT INDUCED SCROLL ON BUTTON TAP |
| --- | --- |
| [image: .] | [image: .] |
| Notice the **address bar at the bottom** hides when the screen is swiped | The bottom address bar **fails to hide** like it normally would with a screen swipe and remains full height |

### Is there a way this swipe up gesture can be triggered artificially with JavaScript to push the address bar down in a working example?

**live site:** https://user-railcoil.github.io/so/scroll/index.html

```js
let
  topButton = document.querySelector( '.top' ),
  bottomButton = document.querySelector( '.bottom' );

window.scroll({
  top: 2500,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});

window.scrollBy({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});

function scrollToBottom() {
  bottomButton.scrollIntoView({
behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
function scrollToTop() {
  topButton.scrollIntoView({
behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}

topButton
  .addEventListener( 'click', scrollToBottom );
bottomButton
  .addEventListener( 'click', scrollToTop );
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;  
 }
body {
  filter: brightness( 105% );
}
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #eee;
}
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  padding: 3rem;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 1rem;
  filter: brightness( 102% );  
}
button:hover, footer:hover {
  background-color: #0cc; color: #eee;
}
button:active, footer:active {
  background-color: #222; color: #222;
}
span {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en-US'>
  <head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/base.css'>
   <style>
      * { box-sizing: border-box; outline: none; }
      div {
        opacity: 0.125; font-size: 2rem;
        line-height: 4rem;
        letter-spacing: 0.25rem;
      }    
      .bottom {
        background-color: #222; color: #eee;
      }    
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <button class='top'>
        scroll to bottom &nbsp; <span>( click / tap )</span>
      </button>
      <div>
        <p>click<p> <p>or</p> <p>tap</p> <p>the</p> <p>button</p>
        <p>above</p> <p>to</p> <p>scroll</p> <p>all</p> <p>the</p>
        <p>way</p> <p>to</p> <p>the</p> <p>bottom</p>
      </div>
      <button class='bottom'>scroll to top</button>
    </main>
    <script src='js/origin.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

These older solutions to older questions do not seem to work on these later versions of IOS ( 15+ )

[How do I hide the address bar on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117377/how-do-i-hide-the-address-bar-on-iphone)

[How to hide a mobile browser's address bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395561/how-to-hide-a-mobile-browsers-address-bar?noredirect=1&lq=1#)

[Is it possible hide iOS browser chrome on a normal webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440386/is-it-possible-hide-ios-browser-chrome-on-a-normal-webpage)

Comment: Hi, have you actually found a solution? Have you ever tried using the `dispatchEvent` method of the [Touch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch) function ?